# Dependency injection: how to get a newable to an injectable without passing it in the constructor?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

Let's say that I have a class `A` that is injected to `B`. `B` is injected to `C` and `C` is injected to `D`.

`D` has a method `doSomething` that receives a newable `NAClass`. `A` needs some information that is stored in `NAClass`. I am looking for the correct way to pass this info to `A` without the need to pass it to `C` and `B`, which don't need it.

One way is to pass this info when building `A` in the factory method, however in that case I break the dependency injection rule in which newables should not be passed to injectables in constructors.

What would be the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate. My question is more focused on classes dependencies and not methods in the same class

Comment: Agreed. The other question is about getting references to injectables; this one is about getting a newable through a chain of injectables. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I've used in a situation something like this is to create another injectable called a `Context`, in your case an `NAContext`. It has a setter and a getter for an `NA`. `D` calls the setter with its `NA` before doing anything that would use `A`, and `A` calls the getter. Of course you have to pay attention to concurrency.

Concrete example: In a Java web app, a `Controller` has access to the current `Request`. The `Controller` also has a bunch of components injected into it and they have components injected into them and so on. Some components need to know whether a user is logged in, which depends on the current `Request`. So make an `AuthenticationContext` with a `ThreadLocal<Request>`, inject it into the `Controller` and all components that care about authentication, and have the controller call `authenticationContext.setRequest(request)` before doing anything with other components (and `setRequest(null)` when it's done to prevent leakage into the next request handled by that thread).

Comment: It is a nice option. However, in such case it would be very hard to another developer to understand who is responsible for initializing the context used in A - It is not clear that D is responsible for that

Comment: True enough -- in the web app example it would be done in one place in a filter, not in each controller.